# Как проверить метод?

Tags: java, junit

Если метод `сook` в конечном счёте правильно отрабатывает, то он должен что-то вывести. Так вот как в JUnit тесте проверить, что метод `cook` что добавил ?

```
public String tasteToString() {
    switch(taste) {
        case SWEET: return "Sweet";
        case SOUR: return "Sour";
        case SALTY: return "Salty";
        case BITTER: return "Bitter";
    }
    return "Tasteless";

public void cook (List<Food> foods, String name, Veget veget) {
    int rand = new Random().nextInt(4);
    Food f = new Food(name);
    switch (rand) {
        case 0: f.setTaste(Taste.SWEET); break;
        case 1: f.setTaste(Taste.SOUR); break;
        case 2: f.setTaste(Taste.SALTY); break;
        case 3: f.setTaste(Taste.BITTER); break;
    }
    f.setVeget(veget);
    foods.add(f);
}
```

Comment: Для теста нужен *неслучайный* генератор случайных чисел.

Comment: да, поскольку у меня тут идёт рандом,  я не могу проверить, что КОНКРЕТНО он добавит, т.к. зарание я не знаю что он добавит, но я думаю можно проверить на то, что он вообще хоть что-то добавил(не важно что).

Comment: все просто, сравниваем количество элементов листа, до вызова метода, с количеством элементов после вызова

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы можно было протестировать такой метод, надо из него выносить `new Random()`, иначе тест будет некорректный, например если в одной из веток выполнения у Вас не будет добавления в лист, то вы с только с определенной вероятностью в тесте на это наткнетесь. Это неверно. Такой тест хуже отсутствия теста.

[java sandbox](http://tpcg.io/6YPy7F)

`Kitchen.java`

```
import java.util.List;

class Food {

    private Taste taste;
    private Veget veget;

    public Food(String name) {}

    public void setTaste(Taste taste) {
        this.taste = taste;
    }

    public void setVeget(Veget veget) {
        this.veget = veget;
    }

    public Taste getTaste() {
        return taste;
    }
}

enum Veget{
    PEPPER
}

enum Taste {
    SWEET, SOUR, SALTY, BITTER
}

class Kitchen{
    IRandom randomGenerator;

    public Kitchen(IRandom randomGenerator){
        this.randomGenerator = randomGenerator;
    }

    public void cook(List<Food> foods, String name, Veget veget) {
        int rand = randomGenerator.nextInt(4);
        Food f = new Food(name);
        switch (rand) {
            case 0:
                f.setTaste(Taste.SWEET);
                break;
            case 1:
                f.setTaste(Taste.SOUR);
                break;
            case 2:
                f.setTaste(Taste.SALTY);
                break;
            case 3:
                f.setTaste(Taste.BITTER);
                break;
        }
        f.setVeget(veget);
        foods.add(f);
    }
}

interface IRandom {
    int nextInt(int i);
}
```

`KitchenTest.java`

```
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class KitchenTest {
    @Test
    public void cook() throws Exception {
        IRandom randomMock = new IRandom() {
            @Override
            public int nextInt(int i) {
                return 0;
            }
        };
        List<Food> foods = new ArrayList<Food>();
        Kitchen k = new Kitchen(randomMock);
        k.cook(foods, "a", Veget.PEPPER);
        org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(foods.get(0).getTaste(), Taste.SWEET);
    }
}
```